# Mojo $c->reply->exception vs die?

Tags: perl, exception, mojolicious, die

They seem to do the same thing.

```
$c->reply->exception('foo');
return;
```

vs

```
die "foo\n";
```

Should I chose one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter is easier to read, can be trapped at the appropriate level if needed, and can include stack traces and context in development mode via automatic [Mojo::Exception](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Exception) wrapping. It also will act appropriately in a promise handler or async sub, causing the promise to be rejected.

You can see exactly how it's handled here (`$next->()` is the call to the dispatch chain): https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-8.33/lib/Mojolicious.pm#L208-214